# how can I add fonts to my webpage if I downloaded from any website?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I downloaded zip file of fonts from a website. I extract and also install the file which comes there in the extracted folder. But I am not abled to use it in my webpage. I use the fontFace property. But As a beginner I do not how to use. can any one please help me to link those fonts to the webpage

Comment: It's possible you don't have a license for these fonts, if you use commercial fonts without a license you could get into some trouble. If the fonts are available on a CDN that's the best way to use them, you don't even need what you downloaded. Google Fonts has a large number of good fonts available.

Comment: If you insist on using the ones you downloaded they may need to be converted to a format that can be downloaded by a webpage, but your question doesn't even mention what format these fonts are. There are free tools to do this. This question can largely be answered with specific questions on a Google search. I can also warn you that there are a lot of really terrible free fonts that have lots of mistakes in them that will cause problems and not render very well.

Comment: ok I will try to use standard fonts. thank you for your reply